# Why does JVM randomly crashes on Windows Server 2012 due to NTDLL.DLL?

Tags: java, crash, jvm, glassfish-4.1, ntdll

My production server occasionaly crashes the java.exe sevice and therefore myApplication Server Glassfish 4.1. It happens randomly and so far I couldn't find a reason to explain such behavior.

Checking Win Server 2012 Event Viewer, it is stated that the Application Error is due to conflict with NTDLL.DLL.

Down below I post the dump collected after one of these crashes:

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=130971776990222439a
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=60c166c2-ba16-11e5-8100-22000afdaf63
IntegratorReportIdentifier=60c166c1-ba16-11e5-8100-a22000afdaf63
NsAppName=java.exe
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=java.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=8.0.650.17
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=56145db1
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=StackHash_6589
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=6.3.9600.18185
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=5683f0c5
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=c0000374
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=PCH_2E_FROM_ntdll+0x00000000000913EA
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=6589
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=6589bd364537aa3998376ce788c85b36
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=ceeb
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=ceebd98f2e612b8c0235a9736a6de63a
UI[2]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe
UI[5]=Check online for a solution (recommended)
UI[6]=Check for a solution later (recommended)
UI[7]=Close
UI[8]=Java(TM) Platform SE binary stopped working and was closed
UI[9]=A problem caused the application to stop working correctly. Windows will notify you if a solution is available.
UI[10]=&Close
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.17810_none_6240b9c7ecbd0bda\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\verify.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\java.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\instrument.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\zip.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\system32\bcryptprimitives.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\net.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\nio.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\management.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\attach.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\awt.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\sunec.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\server\applications\server_amazon\WEB-INF\lib\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64\JLinkNativeLibrary.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\system32\COMDLG32.dll
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=Java(TM) Platform SE binary
AppPath=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=B83E0FFFC973469340275FB99F876701
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: This says Windows 2012 R2 is supported http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html  You could try update 66 to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hadn't had any crash lately after Windows Update. Let's hope this solution become final. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: That might suggest it was a bug in an older version.

Comment: @Rodrigo Mastropietro: we have exact same issue with windows 2012 server R2. Can you please give us more details on the window update that you performed which resolved the issue and that if the issue ever re-occurred? You can have a look at the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502918/java-application-randomly-crashes-with-dll-issues?noredirect=1#comment70215653_41502918) where i have posted my question for further details of our issue. Any help here is highly appreciated.