# Java application randomly crashes with DLL issues

Tags: java, windows, dll, java-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Java application which communicates with .Net application via com. Of late (since we have migrated from **Windows Server 2003** to **Windows Server 2012 R2**) the Java application keeps on crashing randomly.

Some times we will see the application crashed and all related consoles closed where as sometimes we observer the application and console are still there but that it has hanged. A restart of the application resolves the issue most of the time.

The event views in the windows system will point to some issue with DLL. The issue that I have is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779675/why-does-jvm-randomly-crashes-on-windows-server-2012-due-to-ntdll-dll) but we are using **Java 8 update 71 32 bit** on a **Windows Server 2012 R2** so I don't think the solution is applicable to us.

Can someone please help me with this?

Listed below is the error log that we would get in windows event viewer.

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=131281548825671250
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=c0ed1792-d3d2-11e6-bbd4-547879605a0a
IntegratorReportIdentifier=c0ed1791-d3d2-11e6-bbd4-547879605a0a
WOW64=1
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=java.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=8.0.710.15
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=5679f9aa
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=ole32.dll
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=6.1.7600.16385
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=4a5bdac7
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=c00000fd
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=0002c8cc
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7600.2.0.0.272.7
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=7dd2
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=7dd2f8e82f91d939236dc5c2a70daa51
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=b1e2
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=b1e22acb6c6285591c95bac47c6c41b9
UI[2]=E:\java\jdk-8u71-32bits\bin\java.exe
LoadedModule[0]=E:\java\jdk-8u71-32bits\bin\java.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SYSFER.DLL
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16385_none_421189da2b7fabfc\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\syswow64\psapi.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[20]=E:\java\jdk-8u71-32bits\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
LoadedModule[21]=E:\java\jdk-8u71-32bits\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[27]=E:\java\jdk-8u71-32bits\jre\bin\verify.dll
LoadedModule[28]=E:\java\jdk-8u71-32bits\jre\bin\java.dll
LoadedModule[29]=E:\java\jdk-8u71-32bits\jre\bin\zip.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[33]=E:\java\jdk-8u71-32bits\jre\bin\net.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\JTailor\com6402\bin32\ntvinv.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\system32\mtxex.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\system32\COMSVCS.DLL
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\system32\ATL.DLL
LoadedModule[50]=C:\JTailor\com6402\bin32\International\ntvinvenglishresourcedll.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\system32\MFC42.DLL
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\system32\ODBC32.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\system32\odbcint.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\system32\SXS.DLL
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
LoadedModule[62]=E:\java\jdk-8u71-32bits\jre\bin\nio.dll
File[0].CabName=AppCompat.txt
File[0].Path=WER6D18.tmp.appcompat.txt
File[0].Flags=65538
File[0].Type=5
File[0].Original.Path=C:\Users\tradeblade\AppData\Local\Temp\WER6D18.tmp.appcompat.txt
File[1].CabName=WERInternalMetadata.xml
File[1].Path=WER6E03.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
File[1].Flags=65538
File[1].Type=5
File[1].Original.Path=C:\Users\tradeblade\AppData\Local\Temp\WER6E03.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
File[2].CabName=memory.hdmp
File[2].Path=WER6E13.tmp.hdmp
File[2].Flags=2097152
File[2].Type=3
File[2].Original.Path=C:\Users\tradeblade\AppData\Local\Temp\WER6E13.tmp.hdmp
File[3].CabName=minidump.mdmp
File[3].Path=WER7DCD.tmp.mdmp
File[3].Flags=2162690
File[3].Type=2
File[3].Original.Path=C:\Users\tradeblade\AppData\Local\Temp\WER7DCD.tmp.mdmp
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=Java(TM) Platform SE binary
AppPath=E:\java\jdk-8u71-32bits\bin\java.exe
```

Some additional information. Most of the times the crash in windows dump will point to on of the follwoing

1. ntdll.dll
2. combase.dll
3. ole32.dll
4. RPCRT4.dll

Attached below is one of the screen grabs from event viewer.
[image]

**Edit 1:**
Below is the windows 2012 server R2 details
[image]

Comment: looking at [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html) Windows 2012 32-bit is not listed...

Comment: @Bagus Tesa: Windows 2012 server R2 is 64 bits. Java 8 update 71 is 32 bits. In the link they just talk about java 8 and not the bit. The link clearly says "On 64-bit operating systems (OSs), both 32-bit and 64-bit Java virtual machines (JVMs) are certified, except where noted".

Comment: look on error code - `0xc00000fd` - this is `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW` - so some infinite recursion or huge stack allocation (not think for java) during remote call (`rpcrt4.dll` in stack trace). now most helpful will be look on stack during crash. from what all is begin

Comment: also possible incompatible in interface definition between .Net and java. like `ULONG` vs `ULONG_PTR` which the same in x86 but different in x64. if take to account bug begin when you migrate from x86 to x64.

Comment: @RbMm: Thanks for your help. I might me sounding stupid but dont know much abt windows, Can you please also let me know where to look for the file having stack?

Comment: the best of course have debugger attached to process (say windbg) with symbols installed. on crash will be stop in debugger and visible stack trace. also possible configure and collect crash dump - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: weired but true. i have modified the -Xss on windows 2012 server r2 to have 4m value and the issue seems to be gone for now.. I will keep an eye on this as this is not the right fix and also try to find out why do i need this huge stack size